# Is it possible to serve up a different file than the intended one to be downloaded via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

At work they want to do this to prevent people from downloading images easily from our site. They won't go the disable right click option, so they want to do what Flickr is doing:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/scg/12332332454/sizes/l/

If you right click and try to download that image it downloads the entire html page instead. Can this be done via JS or is it something handled by the server?

I know all this goes against usability and doesn't actually prevent people from ripping off images but it's what the ticket I'm assigned asks for.

Comment: the problem is, once the image is visible in browser, the user has already downloaded it. you can make it harder to download it with right click, but ultimately the damage is already done.

Comment: You aren't actually right-clicking the image; you're right-clicking a hidden layer on top of it.

Comment: What flickr is doing is having a div the same dimension as the image overlap the image so when you right-click and save the image, you're actually saving the div which the browser translate as saving the page itself.

Comment: To add to what's been said, a person with modest know-how can grab the image's source URL from the page and download it directly, or simply take a screenshot. Watermarks may be your best approach, though they have limited effectiveness as well.